# Method with Action Delegate Inheritance

Tags: c#

Just for the sake of trying, I wanted to implement a code to incapsulate exceptions catching in a syntactic sugar (after reading a question on SO), so I attempted something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TryCath(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("BANANA");
        },
        DoSomethingWithException, DoSomethingWithCustomException);
    }

    public static void TryCath(Action argTry, params Action<Exception>[] catches)
    {
        try
        {
            argTry();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Type type = ex.GetType();
            catches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Target.GetType() == type)?.Invoke(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Action<Exception> DoSomethingWithException = ex =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    };

    public static Action<CustomException> DoSomethingWithCustomException = ex =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    };
}

public class CustomException : Exception
{

}
```

As expected I get an error cause the method expects an `Action<Exception>` and I'm passing an `Action<CustomException>` too.

What if I want it to accept even `CustomException` which extends `Exception`?

Comment: use generics....

Comment: @DanielA.White That won't work with an array of them, each of a potentially different type

Comment: ah gotcha. hard to follow the OPS code.

Comment: @DanielA.White generics won't work, I tried

Comment: Most people implement this pattern by having a builder, and a succession of `Catch<T>` methods (each of which takes an `Action<T>`, with `where T : Exception`). I.e. `Helper.Try(() => ...).Catch((ThingException e) => ...).Catch((Exception e) => ...)`

Comment: @canton7 but this way you have to declare the method for every type of exception, I wanted to find a way to write only the "catches"

Comment: @MarcoSalerno No you don't...

Comment: To understand why this doesn't work: if you've got an `Action<CustomException>`, you can't call it and pass in an `Exception`. You can pass in something derived from `CustomException`, but not a parent.

Comment: What are you asking... why `Action<CustomException>` cant be passed in place of `Action<Exception>` or how to implement the similar but accepted pattern here as described by canton7?

Comment: I was asking if there was a way to accept as params children classes of Exception as Delegates of Action, I actually know that "normally" you can't

Comment: btw: `x.Target` is **not** the argument to the action, but the instance you call it on.

Comment: ... and `x.Target` will quite often be a compiler-generated class, so it's not normally something you can rely on at all

Comment: True thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally see this written something like:

```
public class TryCatchBuilder
{
    private Exception exception;

    private TryCatchBuilder(Exception exception)
    {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public static TryCatchBuilder Try(Action action)
    {
        if (action is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        try
        {
            action();
            return new TryCatchBuilder(null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new TryCatchBuilder(e);
        }
    }

    public TryCatchBuilder Catch<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : Exception
    {
        if (handler is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));

        if (this.exception is T ex)
        {
            this.exception = null;
            handler(ex);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public void Finally(Action action)
    {
        if (action is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        action();
    }
}
```

And used as:

```
TryCatchBuilder
    .Try(() => throw new ArgumentNullException(""))
    .Catch((ArgumentNullException e) => { })
    .Catch((Exception e) => { })
    .Finally(() => { });
```

**note** the above does not handle the case where an exception occurs for which there is no handler!

... not that I support this pattern at all: use a normal `try/catch` statement.

Comment: Thank you I was "near" somehow